# Insufficient memory error

Tags: c++, memory, opencv

I got insufficient memory error after sometime when i built it. I have tried not to create anymore image if the resultImage != NULL but i still got this problem.

I have done many searching but i couldn`t get a way to solve this problem out. Can anyone help me out with this problem? Its a very simple code only capture the frame from webcam and convert it color.I am using VB2010 C++ express edition and opencv2.4

Well, I'm new to opencv and language c too. Please correct my wrong code if can.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

int main(){
    CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
    if(!capture) return -1;

    char key;

    cvNamedWindow("Frame");

    IplImage* frameImage = NULL;
    IplImage* resultImage = NULL;
    IplImage* HSVImage = NULL;

    while(1){
        frameImage = cvQueryFrame(capture);
        if(!frameImage) break;

        if(resultImage == NULL){
            resultImage = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frameImage),IPL_DEPTH_8U,3);
            HSVImage = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frameImage),IPL_DEPTH_8U,3);
        }
        resultImage = cvCloneImage(frameImage);

        cvCvtColor(resultImage,HSVImage,CV_RGB2HSV);

        cvShowImage("Frame",HSVImage);

        key = cvWaitKey(20);
        if(key == 27) break;
    }

    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
    cvReleaseImage(&resultImage);
    cvReleaseImage(&HSVImage);
    cvDestroyAllWindows();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem, or what are you asking?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to write my problem on it. I got insufficient memory error after sometime when i built it. I have tried not to create anymore image if the resultImage != NULL but i still got this problem. Can you help me out with this problem. Thank you

Comment: Edit the original post to add that, don't put it in a comment.

Comment: you're allocating memory in a tight loop, what do you expect?

Comment: yfrancis, I'm sorry what does "tight loop" means? And how can i solve it?

Comment: `resultImage = cvCloneImage(frameImage);` over and over again in a loop without releasing the image is probably **not** a good thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most probably `cvCloneImage()` allocates memory which never got released. try to use this:

```
IplImage* HSVImage = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frameImage),IPL_DEPTH_8U,3);

while(1){
    IplImage* frameImage = cvQueryFrame(capture);
    if(!frameImage) break;

    cvCvtColor(frameImage,HSVImage,CV_RGB2HSV);

    cvShowImage("Frame",HSVImage);

    cvReleaseImage(frameImage);

    key = cvWaitKey(20);
    if(key == 27) break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for your solution. Yes it work after i stop using cvCloneImage().